# Why doesn't the normal flow element accommodate the floati element?

Tags: html, css, css-float

My understanding is that when you set the "float: left" property to an HTML element, basically, the following steps occur:

1. The element with the property "float:left" is taken out of the
   normal flow.
2. The other elements are positioned in a normal way as if that element
   did not exist.
3. Now, the floating element is "snapped" as far left and up as
   possible until it touches the edge of the page or touches the edge
   of another element.

In this example:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="boxBlue"></div>
    <div id="boxGreen"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css:**

```
div{ 
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  border:8px solid #333;
}
#boxBlue{  
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;      
}
#boxGreen {  
  background-color:green;
}
```

> If in the blue box I put the property "float:left", why the green box
> is not "accommodated" to the blue and it is put to the side instead of
> being covered by the blue one?

Here you can see what I say, in a more visual way:
https://codepen.io/correocontenedor/pen/rNWxXGo

Comment: because it's a block element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you float the element, it means it will float to the direction and overlap other elements. In this case, you haven't added additional CSS to make them accommodate, but a simple fix for your case will be adding `display:inline-block` to the `#boxGreen` this will make them accommodate. This will display the element by side by side

```css
div{ 
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  border:8px solid #333;
}
#boxBlue{  
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;      
}
#boxGreen {  
  background-color:green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxBlue">
</div>
<div id="boxGreen">
</div>
```

.